# Javascript regular expression to replace "n/a" in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

For the life of me, I can't seem to get a reg expression to replace "n/a" in a string.

I have tried:

```
y = "the example of n/a";

x = y.replace(/(n/\a)/g, '0');
```

throws an error. I have also tried many variations with no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `n/\a` should be `n\/a`

Comment: You should swap the slashes. The escaping backslash should *precede* the forward slash that needs escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape properly, do `n\/a`, proper escaping. Example `(n\/a)+`. Remember newlines. `/n`, to detect that `/` . Just escape it `\/n`. Make sense? 
So `x = y.replace(/(n\/a)+/g, '0');`

Comment: Doh! Ha! Thank you!